# Is it shrik to call anyone in Allah's name?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamualaikum..
In our country people have name like Abdur Rahaman,Azizur Rahman,Ahad which are name of Allah.. And people call each other Rahman,Ahad,Khaliq without using Abdur.. Sometimes they don't even know that they are name of Allah..
So is it shrik?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem in my country (Pakistan). But according to following Hadith:

**Holy Prophet Muhammad said: the reward of deeds are according to intention and everybody will get the reward that he has intented.**

So it depends on who is calling the name, we don't know his/her intention. But we must be carefulll

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a problem.

Because even in the name of the prophets or prophet of Islam father`s ,there is also the name of God

‍‍`عبدالله`